# React replacing useState with useReducer while also using a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, components, state, reducers, use-reducer

so I am making a budget tracking app where the user can add their income sources to an incomes list and expenses to an expenses list, and I got it working, but I wanted to see if I could use useReducer instead of using useState so many times. This is where I am stuck since I am not sure what to return in the reducer.

I am using 2 state objects, incomes and expenses. Basically for now I want to use a reducer to allow the user to add an income source to the incomes object. I want to see if I could set the incomes object inside the reducer, and when dispatch is called with the action set to ADD_INCOME_ITEM, budgetObj.type will be set to + and setIncomes(incomes.concat(budgetObj)) will be called (the income source will be added to the incomes list). I hope I made this clear!

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import BudgetInput from './components/input/BudgetInput';
import BudgetOutput from './components/output/BudgetOutput';
import IncomeOutputList from './components/output/IncomeOutputList';
import ExpenseOutputList from './components/output/ExpenseOutputList';
    
// custom hook
const useSemiPersistentState = (key, initialState) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    localStorage.getItem(key) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) : initialState
  );
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [value, key])

  return [value, setValue];
};

const App = () => {

  // want to replace these 5 lines with useReducer
  const [incomes, setIncomes] = useSemiPersistentState('income',[{}]);
  const [expenses, setExpenses] = useSemiPersistentState('expense',[{}]);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [type, setType] = useState('+');
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const budgetObj = {
    desc: description,
    budgetType: type,
    incomeValue: value
  }

  const initialbudget = {
    desc: '',
    budgetType: '+',
    incomeValue: ''
  }

  const budgetReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ADD_INCOME_ITEM': //want to set the incomes object here
        return setIncomes(incomes.concat(budgetObj)); // not sure if this is correct??
        // also set state here???
    }
    //will add more cases here
  }
  

  const [budget, dispatchBudget] = useReducer( //reducer, initial state
    budgetReducer,
    initialbudget
  );
  
  
  const handleBudgetObjArray = () => {

    if(budgetObj.budgetType === '+') {
      setIncomes(incomes.concat(budgetObj)); //want to move this to reducer
    }
    else if(budgetObj.budgetType === '-') {
      setExpenses(expenses.concat(budgetObj)); //want to move this to reducer
    }

  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {  
    setDescription(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleSelectChange = (event) => { 
    setType(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleValueChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    console.log(budgetObj)
  }

  const removeInc = (index) => {
     let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("income"));
     items.splice(index, 1);
     setIncomes(items);
  }

  const removeExp = (index) => {
    let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("expense"));
    items.splice(index, 1);
    setExpenses(items);
 }

  return (
    <div className="App">
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
      <div className="top">
        <BudgetOutput />
        
      </div>

      <div className="bottom">
        <BudgetInput 
          descValue={description}
          onDescChange={handleChange}
          onSelectChange={handleSelectChange}
          type={type}
          onBudgetSubmit={handleBudgetObjArray}
          budgetValue={value}
          onValChange={handleValueChange}
        />

        <div className="container clearfix">
          <IncomeOutputList 
            list={incomes}
            removeIncome={(index)=>removeInc(index)}
          /> 
          <ExpenseOutputList
            list={expenses}
            removeExpense={(index)=>removeExp(index)}
          />
          
        </div>
        
      </div>

    </div>
  )
};


export default App;
```

This file is where budgetObj is set:

```
import React from 'react';
import IncomeOutput from './IncomeOutput';


// list will be list of income objects
const IncomeOutputList = ({ list, removeIncome }) => {

    return (
        <div className="income__list">
            <div className="income__list--title">INCOME</div>
            {list.map((item, index, arr) => <IncomeOutput 
                                id={item.id} 
                                value={item.incomeValue} 
                                type={item.budgetType} 
                                desc={item.desc} 
                               // handleButton={handler(index)} 
                                handleButton={()=>removeIncome(index)}
                                />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default IncomeOutputList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useReducer` replaces `useState`.  It *is* your state.  So this right here makes no sense.

```
case 'ADD_INCOME_ITEM': //want to set the incomes object here
    return setIncomes(incomes.concat(budgetObj)); // not sure if this is correct??
```

Those five `useState` lines of your code which include `incomes` and `setIncomes` are going to be totally deleted, so you cannot be using them in your reducer.

It looks like the `initialState` for your reducer is just one budget object.  It needs to be an object that represents the entire component state. Something like this:

```
const initialBudget = {
  description: '',
  type: '+',
  value: '',
};

const initialState = {
  incomes: [{}],
  expenses: [{}],
  budgetObj: initialBudget,
};
```

I am defining the `initialBudget` separately so that we can use it to reset the `budgetObj` easily.

Your reducer handles actions by taking the `state` and the `action` and returning the next state, like this:

```
const budgetReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SUBMIT_BUDGET':
      // I am using spread to clone the object to be safe, might not be 100% neccessary
      const budget = {...state.budget};
      // figure out where to add the current budget object
      const isIncome = budget.budgetType === '+';
      return {
        ...state, // not actually necessary in this case since we are updating every property
        incomes: isIncome ? state.incomes.concat(budget) : state.incomes, // maybe add to incomes
        expenses: isIncome ? state.expenses : state.expenses.concat(budget), // maybe add to expenses
        budgetObj: initialBudget, // reset budget object
      }
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, it makes more sense to me now! Though what I'm still confused about is how would I use my custom hook useSemiPersistentState for the incomes and expenses? As I do want to store the incomes and expenses in local storage.

Comment: Make a copy called useSemiPersistantReducer and replace the useState with useReducer.  Instead of [value, setValue] use [value, dispatch].  The effect would still depend on [value].